# How can i insert org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing logs into DB

Tags: spring, logback, spring-integration, spring-ws

I'm trying to log org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing logs into db.

I add the MessageTracing logger to my logback.xml.

```
<logger name="org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing">
<level value="TRACE"/>
<appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
<appender-ref ref="WebServiceDBAppender" />
</logger>
```

and for inserting them into db i gave another appender-ref which is WebServiceDBAppender. It is my DBAppender which extends AppenderBase.

I override the append method and typed them in logback.xml

I can reach request&response seperately.First org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing.received i got it and then org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing.send.

Is there any way to reach both of them at the same time for inserting db request&response in the same row?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can achieve it only using single method.
2. I suggest you to implement some `ClientInterceptor` and inject it to the `WebServiceTemplate`
3. There is similar interceptor on the matter on server side `PayloadLoggingInterceptor`.
   As far as there is no such solution for client side, I think it won't иу so difficult to wrap that interceptor with `ClientInterceptor` implementation.
4. And here is an extension of `PayloadLoggingInterceptor` how to log `request` and `response` at once:

   ```
   public class PayloadLoggingInterceptor extends org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadLoggingInterceptor {

       private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PayloadLoggingInterceptor.class);

       protected boolean isLogEnabled() {
           return log.isDebugEnabled();
       }

       protected void logMessage(String message) {
           log.debug(message);
      }

      @Override
      public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) throws Exception {
           if (isLogEnabled()) {
                logMessage("------------START-----------");
                logMessageSource("Request: ", getSource(messageContext.getRequest()));
                logMessageSource("Response: ", getSource(messageContext.getResponse()));
                logMessage("------------END-----------");
           }
           return true;
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: And how to add "PayloadLoggingInterceptor" to the "org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate"? I have WebServiceTemplate which has some interceptors.